# Django Foreign Key many to one not working

Tags: python, html, django, foreign-keys

I am abit confused on how to make a foreing key work with many to one relationship.

I have 2 Models, auditsmodel (Which is the model containing the data) and dv_mode(Containing data validation as options for the answers).

I have created a Foreign key in auditsmodel to reference the Data validation options.

Models.py

```
class dv_model(models.Model):
    # auditsModelKey = models.ForeignKey(auditsModel, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    Defect_Area_dv = models.CharField(_('Defect Area dv'), max_length=200)
    Key_Driver_dv = models.CharField(_('Key Driver dv'), max_length=200)
    Sub_Key_Driver_dv = models.CharField(_('Sub Key Driver dv'), max_length=200)
    QS_Login_dv = models.CharField(_('QS Login dv'), max_length=200)
    QS_Name_dv = models.CharField(_('QS Name dv'), max_length=200)
    Status_dv = models.CharField(_('Status dv'), max_length=200)
    Metric_name_dv = models.CharField(_('Metric name dv'), max_length=200, default='')
    Correct_Associate_Action_dv = models.CharField(_('Correct Associate Action dv'), max_length=200)
    Correct_investigator_Action_dv = models.CharField(_('Correct investigator Action dv'), max_length=200)
    Action_Correctly_Captured_dv = models.CharField(_('Action Correctly Captured dv'), max_length=200)
    Audit_Outcome_dv = models.CharField(_('Audit Outcome dv'), max_length=200)
    Defect_Area_Investigator_dv = models.CharField(_('Defect Area Investigator'), max_length=200)
    Document_Name_dv = models.CharField(_('Document Name dv'), max_length=200)
    Document_Type_dv = models.CharField(_('Document Type dv'), max_length=200)
    Type_of_Audit_dv = models.CharField(_('Type of Audit dv'), max_length=200)
    If_Correctly_Captured_No_dv = models.CharField(_('If Correctly Captured No dv'), max_length=200)
    Country_dv = models.CharField(_('Country dv'), max_length=200)
    Region_dv = models.CharField(_('Region dv'), max_length=200)
    Key_Driver_unique_dv = models.CharField(_('Metric name dv'), max_length=200, default=None)
    Sub_Key_Driver_unique_dv = models.CharField(_('Metric name dv'), max_length=200, default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Defect_Area_dv


class auditsModel(models.Model):
    Dv_model = models.ForeignKey(
        dv_model,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True
    )
    # auditsModelKey = models.ForeignKey(dv_model, on_delete = models.CASCADE, default = '')
    country = models.CharField(_('country'), max_length=200, default='')
    qs_login = models.CharField(_('qs_login'), max_length=200, default='')
    Status = models.CharField(_('Status'), max_length=200, default='')
    seller_id = models.CharField(_('seller_id'), max_length=200, default='')
    Task_ID = models.CharField(_('Task_ID'), max_length=200, default='', primary_key=True)
    associate_queue = models.CharField(_('associate_queue'), max_length=200, default='')
    associate = models.CharField(_('associate'), max_length=200, default='')
    metric_wk_no = models.CharField(_('metric_wk_no'), max_length=200, default='')
    associate_action = models.CharField(_('associate_action'), max_length=200, default='')
    correct_associate_action = models.CharField(_('correct associate action'), max_length=200, default='')
    Associate_Key_Driver = models.CharField(_('Associate_Key_Driver'), max_length=200, default='')
    Sub_Key_driver = models.CharField(_('Sub_Key_driver'), max_length=200, default='')
    Defect_Area_Associate = models.CharField(_('Defect_Area_Associate'), max_length=200, default='')
    QA_Comments_on_Associate_Action = models.CharField(_('QA_Comments_on_Associate_Action'), max_length=400, default='')
    Metric_name = models.CharField(_('Metric_name'), max_length=200, default='')

    # SIV
    investigator_task = models.CharField(_('investigator_task'), max_length=200, default='')
    investigator_queue = models.CharField(_('investigator_queue'), max_length=200, default='')
    investigator = models.CharField(_('investigator'), max_length=200, default='')
    verification_action = models.CharField(_('verification_action'), max_length=200, default='')
    correct_investigator_action = models.CharField(_('correct investigator action'), max_length=200, default='')
    Investigator_Key_Driver = models.CharField(_('Investigator Key-Driver'), max_length=200, default='')
    Defect_Area_Investigator = models.CharField(_('Defect Area Investigator'), max_length=200, default='')
    QA_Comments_on_investigator_Action = models.CharField(_('QA Comments on investigator Action'), max_length=200,
                                                          default='')
    General_Notes = models.CharField(_('General_Notes'), max_length=200, default='')

    Action_correctly_captured = models.CharField(_('Action_correctly_captured'), max_length=200, default='')
    Audit_outcome = models.CharField(_('Audit_outcome'), max_length=200, default='')
    associate_resolve_date = models.CharField(_('Audit_outcome'), max_length=200, default='')
    Type_of_audit = models.CharField(_('Type_of_audit'), max_length=200, default='')
    If_data_correctly_captured = models.CharField(_('If_data_correctly_captured'), max_length=200, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Audit: {self.country}-{self.qs_login}-{self.Status}-{self.seller_id}-{self.Task_ID}-{self.associate_queue}-{self.associate}-{self.metric_wk_no}-{self.associate_action}-{self.correct_associate_action}-{self.Associate_Key_Driver}-{self.Sub_Key_driver}-{self.Defect_Area_Associate}-{self.QA_Comments_on_Associate_Action}-{self.Metric_name}-{self.investigator_task}-{self.investigator_queue}-{self.investigator}-{self.verification_action}-{self.correct_investigator_action}-{self.Investigator_Key_Driver}-{self.Defect_Area_Investigator}-{self.QA_Comments_on_investigator_Action}-{self.General_Notes}-{self.Type_of_audit}-{self.Action_correctly_captured}-{self.Audit_outcome}-{self.associate_resolve_date}-{self.If_data_correctly_captured}"
```

Then in the view.py i referenced the fields in the data validation(dv_model) to match the ones in the main model(auditsmodel)

Views.py:

```
def auditFormPage(request, pk):
    model = auditsModel.objects.filter(qs_login=request.user)
    form = auditForm()
    
    try:
        data = auditsModel.objects.get(Task_ID=pk)

        form = auditForm(instance=data)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            correct_action = request.POST.get('correct_action')
            key_driver = request.POST.get('key_driver')
            defect_area = request.POST.get('defect_area')
            defect_area = str(defect_area)
            metric = request.POST.get('metric')
            QA_comment = request.POST.get('QA_comment')
            
            data.correct_associate_action = correct_action
            data.Associate_Key_Driver = key_driver
            data.Defect_Area_Associate = defect_area
            data.save()
            form.save()
    except auditsModel.DoesNotExist:
        pass

    context = {
        "items": model,
        "form": form
    }
    return render(request, "main/auditform.html", context)
```

This is my forms.py:

```
class auditForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = auditsModel
        fields = '__all__'

    # RADIO BUTTONS
    CHOICES = [('Defect', 'yes'),
               ('No Defect', 'no')]
    CHOICES_Action_correctly_captured = [('yes', 'yes'), ('no', 'no')]
    Audit_outcome = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=RadioSelect())
    Action_correctly_captured = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES_Action_correctly_captured, widget=RadioSelect())
    #Defect_Area_Associate = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=dv_model.objects.values_list('Defect_Area_dv', flat=True).distinct(), widget=forms.Select)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(auditForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Makes the field un-editable

        # FIELDS-----------

        # IPV COMMENT BOX
        self.fields['QA_Comments_on_Associate_Action'].widget = forms.Textarea(
            attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'style': 'height: 100px'})  # Sets the size of the widget
        # SIV COMMENT BOX
        self.fields['QA_Comments_on_investigator_Action'].widget = forms.Textarea(
            attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'style': 'height: 100px'})  # Sets the size of the widget

        # ENABLE/DISABLE FIELDS
        self.fields['country'].disabled = True
        self.fields['associate_resolve_date'].disabled = True
        self.fields['qs_login'].disabled = True
        self.fields['associate_resolve_date'].disabled = True
        self.fields['seller_id'].disabled = True
        self.fields['Task_ID'].disabled = True
        self.fields['associate_queue'].disabled = True
        self.fields['associate'].disabled = True
        self.fields['metric_wk_no'].disabled = True
        self.fields['associate_action'].disabled = True

        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].required = False
            if field != "qs_login" and field != "Status" and field != "associate_resolve_date" and field != "QA_Comments_on_Associate_Action" and field != "Audit_outcome":
                self.fields[field].widget.attrs['class'] = "form-control"
# -----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `Lookups that span relationships` method in this document. Simple add the name of table for more explicit. (or google that term for more detail information)

With this sample model:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tagline = models.TextField()

Blog.objects.filter(entry__headline__contains='Lennon')
```

If you would stick with your way, I suggest you print out the raw query and see what wrong and trace the solution after that.

```
q = Query.objects.values('val1','val2','val_etc')
print(q.query)
```

Try the query first if It is correct in all ways, before developing further. Or else you gonna lose tracks and do not know which step is incorrect.